# "Fork choice rule" : A general term? or a specific algorithm?

Tags: blockchain-fork, ethereum, terminology, best-chain

Is "Fork choice rule" a general term including all the algorithms used for choosing a branch among other branches in a fork (including longest chain rule in Bitcoin etc) ? 
Or is it a specific algorithm designed for Casper Ethereum ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fork choice rule is a general term.

For some history I've found, one of the early written descriptions of the term is from March 2017
https://medium.com/@VitalikButerin/minimal-slashing-conditions-20f0b500fc6c

> A fork choice rule is a function, evaluated by the client, that takes
>   as input the set of blocks and other messages that have been produced,
>   and outputs to the client what the “canonical chain” is.

August 2015 may be the first time "fork-choice rule" was written in a blog post.
https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/08/01/introducing-casper-friendly-ghost

The 2013 [GHOST](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/881.pdf) paper is one of the earliest, prominent publications of a fork choice rule different from Bitcoin's, but it did not specifically mention the term.